# How to get databse list at runtime using servlet and jsp?

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, oracle, servlets

I am facing the problem of listing all databases. I have the **username** and **password** of all **mysql database** and **oracle database**.

I have the following form:

```
<form action="databasetype" method="post" name="databasetype">
    <label>Database Type:</label>
    <select name="databasetype" id="databasetype">
        <option>select database type</option>
        <option value="mysql">mysql</option>
        <option value="sqlserver">sql Server</option>
    </select></br>
    <label>User Name:</label><input type="text" name="username"></br>
    <label>password:</label><input type="password" name="password"></br>
    <input type="submit" value="select">
</form>
```

From above I get the username, password and database type. Based on the above input I need to connect to the respective database server and list out the database and establish the connection with the listed database.

Comment: You can't connect to a MySQL server with pure HTML, you need a backend. Where's your backend code?

Comment: what did you try? It'd be nicer if you present your approach and your current problem, so we may help.

Comment: actually, i am going to connect database based on database type that logic is implementing in servlet and jsp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass **databasetype** from JSP to Servlet (as you are doing now),

and Inside your **Servlet**,

You can do like this ...

```
String databaseType = request.getParameter("databasetype");

if(databaseType.equals("mysql"){

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                 "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/servlet", "username", "password");

PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into YOURTABLE values(?,?,?,?)");

....

}else if(databaseType.equals("oracle"){

... //code to connect oracle

}
```